# How to search for terms in title and content using Wikipedia's API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

On Wikipedia search box you can search for a term, e.g. 'lens', in article's title AND content. Using [the search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) however works only with titles. What request do I need to be able to extend the search on article content too?

Comment: The search API should perform "a full text search". Do you have a specific example that is not working as expected?

Comment: If you search for "Nelson Mandela" on the English Wikipedia, you get 5901 [results](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Nelson+Mandela&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%7D&ns0=1), many of them without any mentions of Nelson Mandela in the title. 
Running the Python example from [the search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) gives 10 results. Am I missing some parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) should perform "a full text search". The reason you're receiving only 10 results is most likely because you've not set the `srlimit` parameter which defaults to 10 and you're not continuing the query. You can set `srlimit` to `max` to receive 50 or 500 results (depends on the access level of your account) and in order to get the rest of the results one needs to [continue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Example_4:_Continuing_queries) the query using the parameters given in the last result.

Comment: I guess continuation means [using a loop like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48844795/7388910). It worked, thanks!