# How do I use the rvcontinue parameter in the Mediawiki API using R?

Tags: r, mediawiki-api

Im trying to extract the wikipedia revision history of several hundred pages. However, the Mediawiki API sets the return limit to 500 for any given page(https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions).

The "rvcontinue" parameter allows you to extract the next 500 and so on, but I'm not sure how to automate this in R. (I've seen some examples of Python code ([Why does the Wikipedia API Call in Python throw up a Type Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838505/why-does-the-wikipedia-api-call-in-python-throw-up-a-type-error)), but I don't know how to replicate it in R).

A sample GET request code for one page is appended below, any help is appreciated!

```
base_url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

query_param <- list(action  = "query",
                    pageids = "8091", 
                    format = "json",
                    prop = "revisions",
                    rvprop = "timestamp|ids|user|userid|size",
                    rvlimit = "max",
                    rvstart = "2014-05-01T12:00:00Z",
                    rvend = "2021-12-30T23:59:00Z",
                    rvdir = "newer",
                    rvcontinue = #the continue value returned from the original request goes here                       
)

revision_hist <- GET(base_url, query_param)
```

Ideally my GET request would automatically update the rvcontinue parameter every 500 values until there are none left.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1**

In your first response, you need to extract the value of rvcontinue to feed it into the second query. I'm still tinkering with the loop but here's the basics:

```
# Query 1

base_url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

query_param <- list(action  = "query",
                    pageids = "8091", 
                    format = "json",
                    prop = "revisions",
                    rvprop = "timestamp|ids|user|userid|size",
                    rvlimit = "max",
                    rvstart = "2014-05-01T12:00:00Z",
                    rvend = "2021-12-30T23:59:00Z",
                    rvdir = "newer"                
)

r <- httr::GET(base_url, query = query_param)

parsed <- jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(r, as = "text"))

# Query 2

query_param2 <- list(action  = "query",
                    pageids = "8091", 
                    format = "json",
                    prop = "revisions",
                    rvprop = "timestamp|ids|user|userid|size",
                    rvlimit = "max",
                    rvstart = "2014-05-01T12:00:00Z",
                    rvend = "2021-12-30T23:59:00Z",
                    rvdir = "newer",
                    rvcontinue = parsed[["continue"]][["rvcontinue"]]
)

r2 <- httr::GET(base_url, query = query_param2)

parsed2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(r2, as = "text"))
```

**Original answer**

I haven't solved it completely, but I noticed that you're probably missing `query = query_param` in `http::GET()`. Here I tried using `rvcontinue = "rvcontinue"`, but that doesn't seem to work for now.

```
base_url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

query_param <- list(action  = "query",
                    pageids = "8091", 
                    format = "json",
                    prop = "revisions",
                    rvprop = "timestamp|ids|user|userid|size",
                    rvlimit = "max",
                    rvstart = "2014-05-01T12:00:00Z",
                    rvend = "2021-12-30T23:59:00Z",
                    rvdir = "newer",
                    rvcontinue = "rvcontinue"                       
)

response <- httr::GET(base_url, query = query_param)

parsed <- jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(response, as = "text"))
```

Here's my error message:

```
> print(parsed)
$error
$error$code
[1] "badcontinue"

$error$info
[1] "Invalid continue param. You should pass the original value returned by the previous query."

$error$`*`
[1] "See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/postorius/lists/mediawiki-api-announce.lists.wikimedia.org/&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."


$servedby
[1] "mw1398"
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm also posting my more convoluted solution as a seperate answer (in the event someone looks for it in the future), although I think your solution is more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution here if someone in the future is ever stuck with a similar problem:

```
    getRevHist <- function(titles) {

    base_url= "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" 

    query_param =  list (  action  = "query",
                     titles = titles, 
                     format = "json",
                     prop = "revisions",
                     rvprop = "timestamp|ids|user|userid",
                     rvlimit = "max",
                     rvstart = "2008-01-01T12:00:00Z",
                     rvend = "2021-12-31T23:59:00Z",
                     rvdir = "newer")

     x <- GET(url = base_url, query = query_param)

     y <- fromJSON(content(x, "text"))

     revision_df <- y[[2]][[1]][[1]][[4]][c("revid", "parentid",   "user", "userid", "timestamp")]

    page_title <- y[[2]][[1]][[1]][[3]]

    revision_df_title <- cbind(page_title, revision_df)

    while ("||" %in% y[[1]]) {

      continue_param <- y[[1]][[1]]

      continue_query_param <- list ( action  = "query",
                               titles = titles, 
                               format = "json",
                               prop = "revisions",
                               rvprop = "timestamp|ids|user|userid",
                               rvlimit = "max",
                               rvstart = "2008-01-01T12:00:00Z",
                               rvend = "2021-12-31T23:59:00Z",
                               rvdir = "newer",
                               rvcontinue = continue_param)

      x <- GET(url = base_url, query = continue_query_param)

      y <- fromJSON(content(x, "text"))

      continue_revision_df <- y[[2]][[1]][[1]][[4]][c("revid", "parentid", "user", "userid", "timestamp")]

      revision_df <- rbind(revision_df, continue_revision_df)

      revision_df_title <- cbind(page_title, revision_df)
     }

     return(revision_df_title)

     }
```